# Error #1109 in MySql

Tags: mysql

This is my trigger.

I want to make trigger on 1 table (rezervare).

[Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUHuF.png)

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER verificare_nr_locuri
BEFORE INSERT ON Rezervare
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF ( SELECT Masa.NrLocuri FROM Rezervare, Masa 
    WHERE Masa.NumarMasa = Rezervare.NumarMasa ) < Rezervare.NumarPersoane THEN 
        SET NEW.NumarMasa = NULL;
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO Rezervare VALUES (123,106,2,'2016-12-11','2016-12-24',5);
INSERT INTO Rezervare VALUES (124,106,2,'2016-12-11','2016-12-24',4);
```

When I execute the trigger, it has been created. But, when I insert data into table rezervare, It become

```
#1109 - Unknown table 'rezervare' in field list.
```

How can I resolve this?

[Table](https://gyazo.com/f3309002bf7aeb3d55a9a520794d5321)

Comment: Put your code in your question, don't use a link to a screenshot.

Comment: i can't,i'm not allowed

Comment: You are definitely allowed to paste the text of the code into your question and format it as code. It the fundamental function of the site and isn't restricted.

Comment: update your question and add  the code ..

Comment: Table names are case sensitive on some systems. Are you typing `reservare` or `Reservare`?

Comment: Rezervare in mysql code and in tables list rezervare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might need to use a JOIN for your SELECT clause.

```
BEGIN
IF (SELECT Masa.NrLocuri, Rezervare.NumarMasa FROM Masa JOIN Rezervare
WHERE Masa.NumarMasa = Rezervare.NumarMasa) < Rezervare.NumarPersoane THEN 
    SET NEW.NumarMasa = NULL;
END IF;
```